# Conditional format of specific characters in a cell that contains a formula

Tags: excel, vba

I have cells contains formulas made of TEXT().
I want to do some conditional formatting on these cells using VBA.

My cells contain numbers, symbols.

The code below works well if I type in myself some text in a cell ('abcdef') but doesn't work when the cell contains value generated by TEXT().
As example, characters 2 to 4 need to be bold.

```
For Each c In Range("B11:B16")
    FormatCell c
Next

Sub FormatCell(c As Range)
    c.Characters(2,2).Font.Bold = True  
End Sub
```

Comment: You will need to save the values, overwriting the formulas with the values returned before trying to format the characters.  You cannot format a character of a value returned by a live formula.

Comment: is there any other option? without VBA?
Suppose I have TEXT(A1)&TEXT(A2), I need A2 to be green or bold.

Comment: no, there is no other way.